# How to concatenate Char type elements in Scala

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

I want to compute all the combination of size 3 from the letters of the alphabet (stored in `vocabulary` as `Seq[Char]`) and output each combination as a `Seq[Char]`, while storing it in a sequence.

Here is the definition of the alphabet :

```scala
 val alphabet:Seq[Char] = Seq('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z')
```

I wrote this piece of code.

```scala
def enumProduct3(vocabulary: Seq[Char]): Seq[Seq[Char]] = {
    // vocabulary = alphabet
    val keys:Seq[Seq[Char]] = (for {x<-vocabulary;y<-vocabulary;z<-vocabulary} yield(x + y + z).toSeq).toSeq
  }
```

I get a `type mismatch` error :

```
[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: Seq[Seq[Char]]
```

I searched the Scala API to concatenate Char type elements but didn't find anything.

Comment: You want `yield Seq(x, y, z)`

Comment: I assume you know the standard lib provides a method for that and it's an exercise? ( `subsets`)

Comment: I didn't know that the standard library provides such a method, but it's an exercise, so I assume my teacher doesn't want us to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your `enumProduct3` - yield should be  `Seq(x, y, z)` and method should return value:

```scala
def enumProduct3(vocabulary: Seq[Char]): Seq[Seq[Char]] = {
  // vocabulary = alphabet
  val keys: Seq[Seq[Char]] = for {x <- vocabulary; y <- vocabulary; z <- vocabulary}
    yield Seq(x, y, z)
  keys
}
```

Or just:

```scala
def enumProduct3(vocabulary: Seq[Char]): Seq[Seq[Char]] = for {
  x <- vocabulary; y <- vocabulary; z <- vocabulary
} yield Seq(x, y, z)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a Seq[Char] like Luis Miguel commented in your question you should `yield Seq(x, y, z)`

If you want to concatenate the chars into a String you can use an interpolator:

```
s"$x$y$z"
```